# CLion with "source shellscript.sh"

Tags: c++, clion

(Note: I am completely new to CLion)

I have an application which builds fine, but when I run it from the shell, I need to do

```
make
source shellscript.sh
./applicationBinary
```

for it to run, otherwise libraries and similar won't be found

How do I do the `source shellscript.sh` within CLion (project from CMakeLists.txt)? I tried with External tools, before launch, but it will say that it cannot find the program "source".

The shellscript in question does some export calls, but they are dependent on a different built which is done beforehand, and the paths are not fixed, and instead get written to that script.

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="..."
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="..."
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
etc.
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used CLion, but how about writing a script boiling down to `source shellscript.sh ; ./applicationBinary` and point CLion at that?

Comment: `source` is a bashism. It looks like CLion uses a more POSIX shell, e.g. `sh`, so use `.` instead. Or, if CLion doesn’t use a shell at all, you could probably use something like `sh -ec 'make ; . shellscript.sh ; ./applicationBinary'`.

Comment: Still not. 'Error running 'Activate script': Cannot run program "sh -ec 'make ; ./activate_run.sh; ./applicationBinary'" (in directory "/home/aro/[...]"): error=2, No such file or directory'

Comment: @SinisterMJ Looks like it uses the whole thing as the name of a command. @Quentin’s tip above might be the way to go.

Comment: Tried that too, then it doesn't find the libraries from the exported folders. Neither worked.

Comment: `./activate_run.sh` should have been `. ./activate_run.sh`, because the dot command is the focal point of this bash-to-sh conversion

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the same problem but so far, the only solution I found is to use the build-in cli in clion (pun not intendet). There you can use your workflow you are used to.
([Jetbrains reference link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html))

I'm still looking for a better solution and updated this answer if I found a workaround.